# Default initialization explicit constructor c++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, undefined-behavior, explicit

How does default initialization work in C++11 if the default constructor is explicit? For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
  int x;

  explicit Foo(int y = 7) : x{y} {}
}

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  std::cout << foo.x << std::endl;
}
```

In main, the variable `foo` is default initialized. Based on my understanding, this will call a default constructor, if one exists. Otherwise, no initialization occurs, `foo` contains indeterminate values, and printing `foo.x` is undefined behavior.

There is a default constructor for `Foo`, but it is explicit. Is that constructor guaranteed to be called, or is the last line of the program undefined behavior?

Comment: Let me ask you, what is not explicit in `Foo foo;`?  You have explicitly told the compiler the type you want to use and the name you want to give the object, so why would that not be explicit?

Comment: Failure to pick a suitable constructor doesn't leave a variable uninitialized, it causes a compilation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use is okay. The worst thing that could happen would be that the compiler would not be able to use the constructor since it is explicit and fail to compile. However, defining a variable as you have will correctly call the `explicit` default constructor.

The use of `explicit` for a default constructor prevents uses like the following:

```
Foo some_fn() {
  return {}; // Fails as the default constructor is explicit.
  return Foo{}; // OK
}
```